# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' with H2 and Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am facing an issue with my Spring Boot project and H2 DB and I am not sure how to locate the root of the issue.

I have ran the project localy in STS and it is working as expected, when I move it to a server (redhat with Tomcat 7) I am getting the below error. The only diffrance between both deployments is the JDBC dependancy is only in the pom.xml which is deployed to the server and not locally.

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring_start</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <packaging>war</packaging>
         <name>spring_start</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <itext.version>7.2.4</itext.version> <!-- Extrenal repo-->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- Extrenal repo Start Here-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.04</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Extrenal repo End Here-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>example</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

application properties h2 part

```
#H2 DB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dipattdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
#spring.h2.console.settings.trace=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

error log

```
11-Jan-2023 19:10:19.388 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
11-Jan-2023 19:10:24.270 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/var/opt/rh/jws5/lib/tomcat/webapps/example.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/example]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.isWrapperFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.isWrapperFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 60 more
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.isWrapperFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceUnwrapper.safeUnwrap(DataSourceUnwrapper.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceUnwrapper.unwrap(DataSourceUnwrapper.java:60)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration.lambda$hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider$0(DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.java:73)
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.metadata.CompositeDataSourcePoolMetadataProvider.getDataSourcePoolMetadata(CompositeDataSourcePoolMetadataProvider.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.isDataSourceAutoCommitDisabled(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:167)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.configureProviderDisablesAutocommit(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:161)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.customizeVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 61 more
```

mvn tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree (default-cli) @ diploma.attestation ---
[INFO] edu.aus.oor:diploma.attestation:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.7.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.69:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.69:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.69:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:barcodes:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:font-asian:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:forms:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:hyph:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:io:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.itextpdf:commons:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:kernel:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:layout:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:pdfa:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:sign:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:styled-xml-parser:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.itextpdf:svg:jar:7.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.konghq:unirest-java:jar:3.7.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.24:compile
[INFO] \- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.1.214:runtime
```

I have removed the .m2 file, and I have removed the JDBC part in the server pom with no luck.

Comment: Stop mixing versions of different modules from a framework. You are mixing 2.7 and 3.0 from spring boot that won't work. You also appear to have some ancient versions of `commons-dbcp` on your classpath probably pulled in by one of your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify which modules I am mixing? for commons-dbcp how I can identify where I need to update the version or find the class to fix it? honestly I am not sure what is commons-dbcp used for.

Comment: Your `spring-boot-starter-cache` has version 3.0.0 which is a different version and thus will pull in other dependencies with incompatible things as well. RUle of thumb don't use version tags for `spring-boot-starter` dependencies, those are management by the parent. Your error is about commons-dbcp (a datasource) do a `mvn dependency:tree` to see what is pulling that in.

Comment: I have checked the mvn tree and the lib folder I could not find the commons-dbcp. I am not sure how is this being added now. Could the error resulted from not having the file in the lib folder?

Comment: No it indicates there is an old version in there, due to the abstract method error. Which means you have a newer API but an older implementation. The problem is you are deploying to Tomcat and not running the embedded container, tomcat ships with a version of commons DBCP. I suspect that is the issue and that the version of Tomca tyou are deploying to is unsupported. You need at least tomcat 8.5 if memory serves me well for Spring Boot 2.7 or even 9.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you are correct. after a lot of digging, I found that the project was running on tomcat 9 locally and we have tomcat 7 on the server. I have added both versions in the STS and it only ran on tomcat 9. Thanks for your help M. Deinum.